# What's wrong with this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some system information from domain computers. I run this script but it never ends.

The script generates the computer name into a text file but then it fails to get the required information from each computers.

I'm sure something is missing in the script but I'm not quite familiar with PS scripting.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Get a list of all computer names and export to text file
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select -Expand Name | Out-File Z:\test.txt

#Get the computer name and find the below infromation for each individual computer

get-content -path z:\test.txt | % { 

$computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem
$computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor    
$computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3 }

#Prepare the below information for a CSV file
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
    'Manufacturer' = $computerSystem.Manufacturer    
    'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
    'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB)    
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size)   
    'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption    
    'User' = $computerSystem.UserName    
    'BootTime' = $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
}

#Export the fields you want from above in the specified order

$csvObject | Select User, Model, PCName, OS, CPU, Ram  | Export-Csv 'system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a broken loop which closes at the `}` on the `$computerHDD` line, it overwrites the same variables over and over without using the data, and a broken set of "Get-WMIObject" calls which never try to contact any remote computers.

And a bit of a wasteful design of grabbing all properties and throwing them away, saving to a file and reloading, calculating 10 properties then keeping 6.

And a broken export which only tries to export one object, and looks like it's intended to be in the loop (with the export -append), but isn't in the loop, and would be clunky if it was.

I can't see why it never ends, but that's why it can't work properly.

---

My rewrite attempt would be:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach {

    $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $_.Name

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
        'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
        'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
        'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
        'OS' = $computerOS.caption    
        'User' = $computerSystem.UserName    
    }

} | Export-Csv 'system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The Get-WMIObject calls now connect to remote computers, the loop just calculates the PSCustomObject with only the properties you care about, those fall out of the pipeline, and the entire output of all the customobjects is exported to CSV in one go at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. The script ran perfectly fine when I tested today. I was trying to add a ping option to the computers and only get details from the computers that are online. How do I achieve this?

Comment: If I add : get-content Z:\test.txt If { Test-connection $_ }                                 Else {"$_ is Down" }

Comment: More like `Get-Content z:\test.txt | ForEach { if (Test-Connection $_) {"$_ is up"} else {"$_ is down"}}`